# mv file back to orginal folder in Linux

Tags: bash, restore, mv

I'm relatively new to Linux and had a bit of help so far (thank you all)

My delete code works exactly how I wanted. Now I'm looking to expand it and restore the file back to the original folder.

```
echo "Are you sure you wish to delete this file? (yes/no)"
Yes) echo "$(readlink -f "$1") >>"HOME/DustbinLog" && mv "$1" "$HOME/my-applcations/Dustbin";;

No¦ echo "file still exists!";;
esac
```

This created a log and moved the file perfectly.

Is there a way to read the log file and return the files back to the original locations.

Comment: No, there's no way to do that in general, since if the file is a symlink, you move the symlink and log what the symlink points to, so you don't know where the symlink originally was. If you restore it from the logged path, you'll end up overwriting the pointed-to actual file with a symlink pointing to it. You also have the problem that if you delete two files with the same name, only the most recent will be stored.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the built-in trash?

It's better, and it deals with symlinks and duplicate files correctly, and it will appear in the GUI file manager.

To move a file to the trash use the built-in command `gvfs-trash $file` or `trash-put` from `trash-cli`. To restore use `restore-trash` from the same package. `trash-list` can list the files in the trash.